# Remove element from a pointer and pointer to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

Still learning, this is a segment of code I'm working on and I'm trying to remove an element(s) from a pointer/pointer-pointer. The problem is near the end of the code.

```
int total, tempX = 0;

printf("Input total people:\n");fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d",&total);
printf("You entered:  %i\n", total);

char **nAmer = (char**) malloc(total * sizeof(char*)); //pointer pointer for username
for (tempX=0; tempX<total; tempX++){
   nAmer[tempX] = malloc(21);
}

double *nUmer = (double*) malloc(total* sizeof(double)); //pointer for usernumber

printf("input their name and number:\n");fflush(stdout);

for (tempX = 0; tempX<total; tempX++){
    scanf("%20s %lf", nAmer[tempX], &nUmer[tempX]);
}

printf("Let me read that back:\n");
for (tempX = 0; tempX<total; tempX++){
   printf("Name: %s Number: %lf\n", nAmer[tempX], nUmer[tempX]);
}

char *searcher = (char*) malloc(21 * sizeof(char*)); //temporary string made by the user to compare names
printf("Enter name to remove user(s):\n");fflush(stdout);
scanf("%20s",searcher);
for (tempX = 0; tempX < total; tempX++){
    if (strcmp(searcher,nAmer[tempX])==0){ //what is better to replace this section?
       free(nAmer[tempX]); //I can assume this wont work well
       free(nUmer[tempX]); //I know this is a problem
   }
}
printf("Let me read that back with removed user(s):\n");fflush(stdout);
for (tempX = 0; tempX<total; tempX++){
    printf("Name: %s Number: %lf\n", nAmer[tempX], nUmer[tempX]);
}
```

I know `free (nAmer[tempX]);` works but doesn't allow for the read back after its removal. What would fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't `free(nUmer[tempX]);` because this isn't a pointer.

When you free one of the name pointers, you can set it to `NULL`. Then the loop that prints the array that can skip it.

```
for (tempX = 0; tempX < total; tempX++){
    if (strcmp(searcher,nAmer[tempX])==0){ //what is better to replace this section?
       free(nAmer[tempX]);
       nAmer[tempX] = NULL;
   }
}
printf("Let me read that back with removed user(s):\n");fflush(stdout);
for (tempX = 0; tempX<total; tempX++){
    if (nAmer[tempX]) {
        printf("Name: %s Number: %lf\n", nAmer[tempX], nUmer[tempX]);
    }
}
```

You have another mistake:

```
char *searcher = (char*) malloc(21 * sizeof(char*)); //temporary string made by the user to compare names
```

This should just be `* sizeof(char)` (or you can just leave this out, since `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`).

Luckily this allocates more memory than needed, not less.

Comment: you can't remove the `nUmer` element. You don't need to remove it, you just ignore it because the corresponding `nAmer` element is `NULL`.

Comment: The null shouldn't be printed, because the `if` skips it.

Comment: BTW, a better way to do this would be with an array of pointers to structures, rather than 2 arrays.

Comment: yeah didn't notice that if statement,  I know about structures and linked lists being better for this, but I wanted to learn more about pointers

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Change the pointer in `nAmer` to `NULL` after you freed it, don't change `nUmer`. That way when processing an entry in `nAmer[i]` or `nUmer[i]` you can check if `nAmer[i]` is valid (`!=NULL`) or not (`==NULL`) and ignore the entry if it is invalid.
2. You can move all entries after the removed entry one up in the array and remember that now there are not `total` number of entries but only `total-1` number of entries.

Please do not `free(nUmer[i])`. The entries in `nUmer` are doubles and not pointers. You cannot `free` them.